# Remove the first select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to remove the first option of an select tag when I click on the select tag. Is this possible?

[image: example image]

I don't want to see the first option after that click.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: **<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">---Choose the city---</option>** <-- This way it will be grayed out and will be not up for selection.

Comment: You mean this ------> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekeu4wvn/)?

Comment: Ivan, does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, click on the check mark beside the best answer to solve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use bootstrap add placeholder attribute in your select.

If your not

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You may also want to give the `<select>` the `required` attribute if they must choose a different value.

Comment: It depends on the needs.. But lets add that

Answer (score 10):

You can remove the first option on click with jQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', 'select', function() {
   $(this).find('option').get(0).remove();
});
```

This simply removes the first option of a select tag on click. You need to add an if statement to check if it was already removed.

Comment: Simplicity, answering the OP and not suggesting another framework.

Comment: every time it clicked will remove first option, there should be an if block to check if its the option to be removed.

Answer (score 10):

There's also a simple no-javascript solution:

```html
<select>
    <option style="display: none">--Choose--</option>
    <option>Cheese Cake</option>
    <option>Hot Pockets</option>
    <option>Sausage</option>
    <option>Cookies</option>
    <option>Bacon</option>
</select>
```

(Copied from the comments from @chipChocolate.py)

Answer (score 3):

```
// to remove first...
    document.getElementById("element_id_str").options[0].remove();

//to remove the lot...
    document.getElementById("element_id_str").options.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select required>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just want this:

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" hidden>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very naive way of doing this:

```js
$("#selector").change(function(evt) { //listen to changes of selection
  var theElement = $(this);
  if (!theElement.data("selected")) { //check if flag is not set
    theElement.children("option")[0].remove(); //remove 1st child
    theElement.data("selected", true); //set flag, so it doesn't continue removing items for every change
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option>--Choose--</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Papaya</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the first option  use this

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("select").children().first().remove();           
    });
```

If you want to remove the first option after clicking on the select box use this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var removed=false;       
    $(document).on("click","select",function()
    {
        if(!removed)
        {
            $(this).children().first().remove();
            removed=true;
        }


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("SelectId")[0].remove();
```

Get the first option in the select and remove it.

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Popo Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solutions above just work with one  form, not with many. I added some extra code in order to validate it for many  in your form:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on("change","select",function()
    {
        var x =    $(this).children().first().attr("name");
        var n = x.localeCompare("todelete");

        if (n == 0)
            $(this).children().first().remove();
    });
});
```

Where "todelete" is the name for all first elements [0] defined inside the

Please select value  //all first elem must have the same name

">  //the others another name (can be the same BUT not "todelete")

Answer (score 0):

You need the id or class to remove the item. While testing and debugging I found 'option:first' fails to remove the item. But 'option:first-of-type' always does the work. You can get more info about 'first-of-type' [here :first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

```
$("#ID_or_.CLASS option:first-of-type").remove();
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, I have added some explanation as far my findings. @nik7